# Jquery validation for label field

Tags: jquery, validation

Is it possible to validate or make required field for a label something like this.

```
 <label id="company" name="company">
    <%
       if (request.getParameter("company") != null) {
   request.getParameter("company");
}
%>
</label>
```

For text area we make it require by giving company: Required. But this is a label. Any help ?

Comment: Is this really a question about the jQuery Validate plugin?  If so, please show us your _rendered_ HTML along with the jQuery code for `.validate()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the label  text by using `$('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').html();`.SO you can write jQuery validation for label

```
<label for="company"  class="con_name">Insert Name</label>
$("#formId").validate(
{       
rules:{
    con_name:{required:true, minlength:3},                      
      }  
messages: {
      con_name: 'Insert Name'
      }

});
```

[**SEE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/u6azR/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%
if (request.getParameter("company") != null) {
   %>
   <label id="company" name="company"></label>
   <%
}
%>
```